# Approximating the frequency response of a median filter

Tags: noise, frequency-response, filtering

A median filter is a non-linear and lossy process, so it doesn't have a closed form frequency response as would a FIR filter (say a box filter of the same length) in an LTI system.

- But how closely can something similar to a frequency response of a median filter be approximated?
- How would this scale with the length of a median filter?
- Under what conditions or for what class of signals might this approximation be ballpark "close"?
- For what class of signals might this approximation be very inaccurate?
- What kinds of frequency domain distortion or additive noise does a median filter produce?

Comment: Well it's definitely a low-pass filter, right?  Is there any scenario in which it amplifies high spatial frequencies?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a start, any *non-linear* system will not have an easily-identifiable frequency response. So, it's really a nonsensical question. I intend no offense; nonsensical questions are often the  most enlightening!

However one way to *try* to answer your question is to assume that the LTI filter involved is the `mean` (rather than the `median`) of the windowed data.

Then your question:

> Under what conditions or for what class of signals might this approximation be ballpark "close"?

becomes:

> Under what conditions or for what class of signals might the mean be ballpark "close" to the median.

In that case, for a purely stochastic signal, the mean and median are similar when the probability density function (PDF) of the signal is symmetric about the mean.

> For what class of signals might this approximation be very inaccurate?

When the signal's PDF is "very" asymmetric.

Comment: Ah yes, that might make sense, a very asymmetrical PDF (say, with some outliers), would have a median within the non-out-liears, as well as a mean within the non-out-liers as well.

Comment: A very asymmetrical PDF with just one extreme value could have its mean far from the bulk of the data.  Typical example (ala NNTaleb) is Elon Musk walks into a generic room of 100 people, and the average net worth of the occupants can suddenly jump to over 100X above the median.

Comment: @hotpaw2 Absolutely!  It's like the "Lake Wobegon" statement "all the children are above average." It just takes one below-average to **almost** make it true. :-)